# In a string if at least one lowercase, uppercase , number and special character exists it should print true or else false

Tags: python, string

```py
def solution(a):
    s1=a.strip()
    for i in s1:
        k=i.islower()
        s=i.isupper()
        l=i.isnumeric()
        if k == True and s == True and l == True:
            print('True')

        elif l != True and s!= True and k!=True:
             print('False')

a="Hp1"
solution(a)
```

For now above function contains checking for uppercase, lowercase & number .But While running above script I'm not getting any output. Please help and advance Thanks.

Comment: Add a `print(k,s,l)` right after their assignment, you should understand why you get no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, your `k`, `s` and `l` variables are updated (renewed) with each loop, and the `if` statement will **only** check for one character each time. And as no character can be lowercase, uppercase and a number at the same time, the answer would be `false`. This can be fixed by creating those variables **outside** the `for` loop.

Also, the last two lines of your code is misindented.

My patch:

```
def solution(a):
    s1=a.strip()
    k=False
    s=False
    l=False
    for i in s1:
        if i.islower():
            k=True
        if i.isupper():
            s=True
        if i.isnumeric():
            l=True
        if k and s and l:
            print('True')
            return
    print('False')

#Sample data             
a="Hp1"
solution(a)
a="hp1"
solution(a)
a="hP"
solution(a)
```

Output:

```
True
False
False
```

*Note: ran on Python 3.7.9, Windows 10 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `map`, `any`, and `all`

```py
a="Hp1"
all((any(map(str.upper,a)), any(map(str.lower, a)), any(map(str.isnumeric, a))))
Out[21]: True
```

If you want to check for special cases, you can do that too

```py
import string
string.punctuation
Out[22]: '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

INCLUDING punctuation:

```py
a="Hp1"
all((any(map(str.upper,a)), 
     any(map(str.lower, a)), 
     any(map(str.isnumeric, a)), 
     any(map(lambda x: x in string.punctuation, a)
    )))
    
Out[23]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the variable creation for `a` and the function call `solution(a)` within the function, so it is not being called. Ensure the indentation and spacing is correct and try again.

There are also logic issues. The `islower`, `isupper` and `isnumeric` functions return true if the entire string contains those character types. You will need to think of an alternative approach.

Comment: is there any alternative method to check the same  or cloud you please help me to get the same ..?

Answer (score 0):

> I have used below the way to achieve the above answer it works .Thanks.

```
import string
def solution(a):
    s1=a.strip()
    k=False
    s=False
    z=False
    x=False
    for i in s1:
      if i.islower():
        k=True
      if i.isupper():
        s=True
      if i.isnumeric():
        z=True
      if i in string.punctuation:
        x=True
      if k == True and s == True and z == True and x== True :
        print('True')
        return

    print('False')
 a= "Foobar123@"
 solution(a)
```